# Generate PDF when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript

MY PROBLEM STATEMENT IS,

I have a set of links in a webpage,which was created in javascript.

Now what I want is if anybody clicks the link it should go to that
   corresponding page and a pdf file should generate automatically. In 
   Ubuntu OS there is an option to generate PDF of any page, but how would I use it
   to generate automatically, if need with some condition also.

Answer (score 1):

It is **server side** task to generate PDF or whatever. While javascript is **client side** technique (in your case).

So you need to use some server side technology. So you should let us know what language do you use: PHP, C#, Ruby, Python etc. So we will suggest some ready out of box library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your PDF as you build an other page. Try to use TCPDF plugin (http://www.tcpdf.org/).